# Cargo lambda build does not find OpenSSL development headers

Tags: rust, aws-lambda, openssl, cargo-lambda

I'm trying to write a lambda function for AWS in Rust using cargo-lambda. The example function generated by `cargo lambda new` builds fine when I call `cargo lambda build --release --arm64`. However, when I try to build code I write by following the instructions and examples on https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-rust-runtime & https://www.cargo-lambda.info/guide/getting-started.html, the build fails to find the headers for OpenSSL. I already installed OpenSSL with `pacman -S openssl` and ran `pacman -S linux-headers` for good measure, and tried running `export OPENSSL_LIB_DIR=/usr/lib/` and `export OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/openssl/` as well as setting them in my Fish config file, but neither has worked. I can't get past:

```
cargo:warning=build/expando.c:1:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
cargo:warning=#include <openssl/opensslv.h>
```

I have visually verified the file exists in the directory but for some reason `openssl-sys-0.9.87` fails to find it and panics. Has anyone else encountered this, or does anyone have any ideas I can try? I'm not sure if the problem is with my cargo-lambda setup, my OpenSSL setup, my code, or something else entirely.

This code was generated with `cargo lambda new project_name` and builds fine:

```
use lambda_runtime::{run, service_fn, Error, LambdaEvent};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

/// Main function generated by cargo-lambda
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Error> {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_max_level(tracing::Level::INFO)
        // disable printing the name of the module in every log line.
        .with_target(false)
        // disabling time is handy because CloudWatch will add the ingestion time.
        .without_time()
        .init();

    lambda_runtime::run(service_fn(function_handler)).await
}

/// This is a made-up example.
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Request {
    command: String,
}

/// This is a made-up example of what a response structure may look like.
#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Response {
    req_id: String,
    msg: String,
}

/// This is the main body for the function.
/// Write your code inside it.
async fn function_handler(event: LambdaEvent<Request>) -> Result<Response, Error> {
    // Extract some useful info from the request
    let command = event.payload.command;

    // Prepare the response
    let resp = Response {
        req_id: event.context.request_id,
        msg: format!("Command {}.", command),
    };

    // Return `Response` (it will be serialized to JSON automatically by the runtime)
    Ok(resp)
}
```

This is the code I'm trying to build but getting an error from `openssl-sys-0.9.87` even though it was written in the same project and follows the examples from the online documentation:

```
use lambda_runtime::{run, service_fn, Error, LambdaEvent};
use reqwest::blocking::Client;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use serde_json::{Value, json};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), lambda_runtime::Error> {
    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_max_level(tracing::Level::INFO)
        // disable printing the name of the module in every log line.
        .with_target(false)
        // disabling time is handy because CloudWatch will add the ingestion time.
        .without_time()
        .init();

    let query = service_fn(query_handler);
    run(query).await
}

async fn query_handler(event: LambdaEvent<Value>) -> Result<Value, Error> {
    let (event, _context) = event.into_parts();
    let symbol = event["symbol"].to_string();
    let message = query_price(symbol)?;
    Ok(json!({ "message": format!("{}", message) }))
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
struct PriceQuote {
    pub s: String,
    pub symbol: Vec<String>,
    pub ask: Vec<f32>,
    pub askSize: Vec<u32>,
    pub bid: Vec<f32>,
    pub bidSize: Vec<u32>,
    pub mid: Vec<f32>,
    pub last: Vec<f32>,
    pub volume: Vec<u32>,
    pub updated: Vec<u32>,
}

fn query_price(symbol: String) -> Result<String, reqwest::Error> {
    //let symbol = "AAPL";

    let url = format!("https://api.marketdata.app/v1/stocks/quotes/{}", symbol);
    let client = Client::new();
    let response = client.get(url).send()?;
    let price_quote: PriceQuote = response.json()?;

    let symbol: &String = &price_quote.symbol[0];
    let last_price: &f32 = &price_quote.last[0];

    Ok(format!("Last price for {} is {}", symbol, last_price).to_string())
}
```

Why would one build but not the other? Are the dependencies I added messing with it? Do I have the wrong OpenSSL version? Did I make a mistake? What am I missing? Sorry if these are dumb questions, I'm new to AWS and my head is spinning.

Comment: I wonder if `pacman -S openssl-1.1` would have done the trick.

Comment: To the best of my understanding, the version of the openssl-sys crate used by reqwest doesn't seem to link to newer versions of OpenSSL, now I could be wrong, but I think that's why specifying the most recent "vendored" version of the openssl crate was able to fix it, because it replaced the version imported by reqwest and provided a compatible version of OpenSSL for cargo lambda to build with. If anyone else runs into this problem and doesn't already have Perl 5 and clang to compile the vendored openssl crate then changing the OpenSSL version with their package manager might be worth a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unsure of exactly what went wrong, but it seems the reqwest crate was the root of the trouble. I've never had this problem except when building via cargo-lambda so I imagine it has something to do with Zig?

Either way, it can be solved by adding openssl directly to Cargo.toml:

```
openssl = { version = "0.10.35", features = ["vendored"] }
```

This seems to provide the correct linkage for reqwest and allows cargo lambda to build. Haven't tested if reqwest still works but I see no reason it shouldn't.

Update: The function deploys and reqwest works fine

Comment: Absolute champion for sharing . TY

Answer (score 2):

AWS Lambda functions execute inside Amazon Linux 2 sandboxes, which include only bare minimum functionality to run Rust binaries and do not include OpenSSL. `cargo lambda build` does not build against what's available on a host (build) system, but against what will be available on a guest (runtime) Linux sandbox, hence the failure to find OpenSSL headers. [Cargo Lambda docs](https://www.cargo-lambda.info/guide/cross-compiling.html#known-cross-compilation-issues) mention:

```
`*-sys` libraries are not guaranteed to work unless they are completely linked to your binary
```

The Rust `openssl` crate can be switched to compile and link statically with `openssl = { version = "0.10.35", features = ["vendored"] }` in `Cargo.toml` (as already mentioned by *j-stach*). Analogously, the Rust `reqwest` crate, a HTTPS client dependent on OpenSSL, can be switched to compile and link statically with `reqwest = { version = "0.11.23", features = ["native-tls-vendored"] }` or `reqwest = { version = "0.11.23", default-features = false, features = ["rustls"] }`.

Finally, if you run into the beloved `cargo lambda build` [issue](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/16855) *"unsupported linker arg: --no-undefined-version"*, just downgrade your Rust to 1.69 with `rustup default 1.69`.